# RSpec error: expected: nil, got: [] (compared using ==)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, bdd, rspec-rails

I am trying to test with Rspec this line in controller:

```
@dreams = Dream.public_dreams.includes(:user).where("users.type_id = ?", 5)
```

I am using to test it with this line in controller test:

```
Dream.public_dreams.select { |dream| dream.user.type_id = 5 }.should eq(@dreams)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
expected: nil, got [] (compared using ==)
```

Comment: You've just edited out the part that was causing the problem.  Please either delete your question, or leave the question up and mark one of the answers as accepted...

Comment: @Nikita Would like to see the definition of `public_dream` from `Dream` model. Please update the question with that. :)

Comment: No, this is a different problem than you had before. Changing both the code and the error is not a good way to get people to help you or to build a good knowledgebase for others.

Comment: @NikitaMorshchikhin Erm. I don't see the definition of `public_dreams` method in update.

Comment: @kiddorails What do you mean? It is defined in model dream.rb.

Comment: @NikitaMorshchikhin you haven't provided enough context. Show the code from the RSpec example and the controller method under test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@dreams` is an instance variable, which means it is tied to a class. The `@dreams` in your controller is not the same as the `@dreams` in your test. In Ruby, any reference to an instance variable that has never been set will be `nil`.

You can "fix" your test by doing

`Dream.public_dreams.select { |dream| dream.user.type_id = 5 }.should eq([])`

But you probably want something in that array. You are probably returning nothing because you don't have any data in your database in your test environment (or maybe just not with that ID).

Comment: Thank you very much! I agree with you.